# How to make changes to an AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, aws-marketplace

I have an AMI that I am trying to put on AWS Marketplace. During this process, amazon scans the AMI for potential security vulnerabilities. The scan found several in my AMI.

How can I fix them?

Do i:

- Delete the current AMI, go back to the EC2 instance from which the AMI was created, make the changes and create a new AMI?
- Or Can I somehow start the current AMI, SSH into it and make the necessary changes?

Answer (score 4):

The best practice is to build a repeatable process for creating your AMIs from a base operating system image (typically AWS Linux, Ubuntu, etc.).  The reason is that you have many more updates ahead of you:

- You might not succeed at fixing the identified issues completely to Amazon's satisfaction
- Future scans may find new, different issues
- AWS Marketplace staff will manually check some things with your AMI
- You might find your own bugs
- You will eventually want to deploy new software versions

Yes, you could launch an instance from your your image, modify it, save it, and make a new image.  It might be worth doing that to learn something about the AMI scanning criteria.

But you would not make any progress towards a reliable, repeatable image building flow.  I strongly recommend looking into tools like [Packer](https://www.packer.io/) that can help you automate the AMI building process.